# Missing NULL keyword error when trying to avoid duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to do an update to a table that contains records pertaining to people under Oracle 11g.  I have a column that contains IDs, some of which contain hyphens.  The table has a constraint on this ID so two different people can't have the same ID.  My goal is to remove the hyphens, while avoiding any constraint violations when I do an update.  So I tried this query to detect records that would violate the constraint:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM people
WHERE externalid LIKE '%-%' AND
replace(externalid, '-') IS IN (SELECT externalid FROM people);
```

This then fails with an ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword.  I know this is due to that last line, but I don't know how else to structure that part of the query to detect the records that have the non-hyphenated ID already in use.  How can I detect these records that would violate the constraint?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `IS` keyword is used as in `something IS NULL`, not with the `IN` keyword. That's why the database thinks that there is a NULL missing. Just remove the `IS`:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM people
WHERE externalid LIKE '%-%' AND
replace(externalid, '-') IN (SELECT externalid FROM people);
```

Comment: Oh god, you're right.  I totally had a brainfart there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work in oracle but worth a try:

```
SELECT * FROM people p1
Inner Join people p2 on replace(p1.externalid, '-') = p2.externalid
and p1.externalid < p2.externalid --prevents duplicate matches
Where p1.externalid LIKE '%-%'
```